# How to set current time (-zone) for Logging?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, timezone, nlog

I use for logging **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and NLog**. The logs are written to **Elasticsearch**. When I look up my logs using **Kibana** all my logs are written at UT what means two houers different to my local time (-zone) MET. I would like to see my logs with my local time at Kibana. **How can I adjust the time zone for logging?**

I add the NLog.config:

```xml
<nlog autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Info" internalLogFile="NLogError.log"
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <targets>
 <target name="Logfile" xsi:type="File"
  fileName="${basedir}dap.log"
layout="${longdate} ${level} ${callsite} -> ${message} ${exception:format=Message,StackTrace}"
  archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/log.{#}.log"
  archiveEvery="Day"
  archiveNumbering="Rolling"
  maxArchiveFiles="14"
  keepFileOpen="false"
  />

  <target xsi:type="Network"
        name="CentralLog"
        newLine ="false"
        maxMessageSize="65000"
        connectionCacheSize="5"
        encoding="utf-8"
        keepConnection="false"
        maxQueueSize="100"
        address="tcp://myurl.org:5544"
        onOverflow="Split">
  <layout type="JsonLayout">
    <attribute name="machinename" layout="${machinename}" />
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}" />
    <attribute name="processname" layout="${processname}" />
    <attribute name="processid" layout="${processid}" />
    <attribute name="sendertimestamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />
    <attribute name="module" layout="dhp DataPickerApi ${logger}" />
    <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception}" />
    <attribute name="activityId" layout="${activityId}" />
  </layout>
 </target>    
</targets>

 <rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="Logfile" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="CentralLog"/>
 </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Probably an option is in your NLog config. Please share your NLog config

Comment: How do you forward the logevents from NLog to Elasticsearch? Do you use filebeat or do you use https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/ ?

Comment: @Julian I add the NLog.config to my initial question. I tried using the line <time type="FastLocal" /> or <time type="AccurateLocal" /> what did not make a difference at the saved time.

Comment: @RolfKristensen I use the nuget package NLog.

var logger = new LoggerFactory().AddNLog().CreateLogger<Program>();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `universalTime=true`?
So instead of this:

```xml
<attribute name="sendertimestamp" 
           layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />
```

Use this:

```xml
<attribute name="sendertimestamp" 
           layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Julian! I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone in the Kibana web.

**Setting-->Advanced---> DateFormat:tz**

to get more info : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html

Comment: Other logs are comming in from other software and there are at the right time. Means now at 12:01 are comming logs with the time 12:01. But my logs are written with the time 10:01. So I think when I adjust Kibana, than the other logs will have a wrong time.  Also it is adjust to my browser time what should be right.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop The industry standard is writing UTC-timestamps when writing JSON. And Elasticsearch really likes JSON. The IJsonConverter in NLog converts to UTC by default (Not sure it can be configured differently).